# Can Windows 7 Jump Lists be made to behave like menus when dragged out with a mouse?

Tags: windows-7, jumplist

On a traditional menu, if you mousedown on the menu title, drag down, then release on a menu item, it will trigger that menu item immediately, e.g. in Notepad:

1. Left mouse button down on File
2. Drag down to New
3. Release mouse button

will start a new file without requiring an additional click.

However, when dragging out a Jump List on Windows 7, you must additionally click the desired item to launch it. Is there any way to change this behavior?

Comment: It works as expected for me on Windows 7 Ultimate. Which edition of Windows 7 do you have? Are you using any mouse software drivers (e.g. Microsoft IntelliPoint, Logitech SetPoint)?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 Professional, with Logitech SetPoint. Do the mouse drivers make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

I had Windows 7, where it worked

Now that I have Windows 8, it doesn't.
I have W8 64 on desktop, W8.1 86 on laptop (had W8 86)

My classmate had Windows 8 64, now has 8.1 64 on his pc and it does work.

Answer (score 0):

> Can Windows 7 Jump Lists be made to behave like menus when dragged out with a mouse?

Short answer: no.

> On a traditional menu, if you mousedown on the menu title, drag down, then release on a menu item, it will trigger that menu item immediately.
>
> However, when dragging out a Jump List on Windows 7, you must additionally click the desired item to launch it.

A traditional menu is exactly that, a menu. Like almost all interface elements in Windows, menus are windows, but a special kind of window; they are a construct of the operating system and have a window-class of `#32768`. Some window classes (including dialog boxes which have a window-class of `#32770`), are automatically handled internally (by default) by the operating system without the program that created them needing to do anything special with them.

Most other windows however are given custom window classes and the program that creates them has to handle them on their own (e.g., painting the window, handling input, etc.)

Jump-lists are *not* menus, they only emulate them. They have a window-class of `DV2ControlHost` and are handled by Explorer (`explorer.exe`)—which is itself essentially just a Windows program. Jump-lists are not handled by Windows itself like menus are.

This is why they behave differently from menus (I don’t know why some people have said it works the same for them; maybe they just misunderstood what is being asked).

> Is there any way to change this behavior?

No, there is no way to do that because it would require making Explorer handle them like real menus. You could try posting a feature request, but conventional wisdom says that most feedback is typically ignored.